# How to use Prolog testing terms?

Tags: testing, prolog, ffi, sicstus-prolog

How to use these expressions?

- SP_term_type()
  Accesses term type
- SP_is_variable()
  Checks whether term is a variable.
- SP_is_integer() 
  Checks whether term is an integer.
- SP_is_float()
  Checks whether term is a float.
- SP_is_atom() 
  Checks whether term is an atom.
- SP_is_compound()
  Checks whether term is compound.
- SP_is_list() 
  Checks whether term is a list.
- SP_is_atomic()
  Checks whether term is atomic.
- SP_is_number()

Comment: This is not how you ask a question on Stack Overflow. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), at least, before you ask.

Answer (score 3):

These C API functions all have individual reference pages in [the SICStus Prolog Manual](https://sicstus.sics.se/documentation.html). The C code in the libraries can probably serve as examples of their use.

In general you should avoid the C API, if possible, since it is so easy to do the wrong thing.